# mongoexport statments transfer to insert statement

Tags: mongodb

I have exported my documents with **mongoexport** and I got something like this:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5661ee327dfef9c9b51dbea9"},"_class":"com.smartinnotec.aposoft.dao.domain.HolidaysWeekAustria", ...
```

Now I would need a statement where I can insert documents over mongoDB console like this:

```
db.HolidaysAustria.insert({ "_id" : ObjectId("166097cf786c8093b3bd31ad"), "_class" : "com.smartinnotec.aposoft.dao.domain.HolidaysAustria", ...
```

Is there a possibility to convert from the first to the second?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you find an answer for that one?

Comment: I'm wondering the exact same thing.